# Doxygen arrows not working

Tags: doxygen

The namespace arrows in the Doxygen-generated documentation that I generated aren't working on a Centos instance (when you click on an arrow, it's supposed to go from horizontal to vertical, and open up members of the namespace). However, it is working on my Mac using the same config file, and it was working on another Centos instance. This happens when GENERATE_TREEVIEW gets set to YES or NO. Any ideas or suggestions?

EDIT: This occurred on a Jenkins build using a Doxygen plugin.

Comment: Post a bug report at http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/trouble.html#bug_reports.

Comment: The problem was the most recent Jenkins build has default security settings that disable Javascript, which breaks Doxygen. I just needed to start Jenkins with the security settings off.